# Проблемы с отображением кириллицы в R 4.0.4

Tags: windows, r, кириллица

После обновления R до последней версии 4.0.4 перестали отображаться надписи на русском. Пока никаких решений не найдено - пришлось откатить до 4.0.3.

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) -- "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out"

>print("Привет")
[1] Привет


R version 4.0.4 Patched (2021-02-27 r80043) -- "Lost Library Book"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

> print("Привет")
[1] "\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442"
```

Две сессии RGui запущены одновременно с настройками поумолчанию. Результат на скриншоте.
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/05/02/utf-8-support-on-windows/  - похоже, нужно правильно выставить кодировку

Comment: наверняка специфично для операционной системы. поэтому лучше указать её явно в виде метки (нажав [edit]).

Comment: На Windows 10 и на Windows 7 проблема одинакова.

Answer (score 1):

Сегодня вышел патч r80061, исправляющий проблему.

> BUG FIXES
>
> The change to the internal table in R 4.0.4 for `iswprint`
> has been reverted: it contained some errors in printability of ‘East
> Asian’ characters.