# Отображение кириллицы в консоли R кодами Юникода

Tags: utf-8, r, кириллица, locale

При попытке вывода кириллицы в консоль через print вижу вот это:

```
> print('абв')
> [1] "\u0430\u0431\u0432"
```

В то же время:

```
> cat('абв')
абв
```

Вывод sessioninfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.4.2         compiler_4.0.4     R6_2.5.0           tools_4.0.4        curl_4.3           tinytex_0.29       telegram.bot_2.4.0 jsonlite_1.7.2    
[9] xfun_0.21
```

Пользоваться cat() не могу, нужен форматированный вывод. В переменных RStudio все кириллические названия тоже отображаются кодами Юникода. Пробовал менять локаль с помощью Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_RU.UTF-8"), эффекта нет.

Comment: Буквально только что уже спрашивали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1251411/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-r-4-0-4, там и ответ есть

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблемы с отображением кириллицы в R 4.0.4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1251411/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-r-4-0-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был баг в самом R, нужно перекачать новую версию (R 4.0.4patched)